# Lenovo Thinkpad beep sound when Lenovo update is available

Tags: lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo Thinkpad beeps continuously whenever new updates are available through the Lenovo update program.  The only way to stop the beep is to restart my computer.  How do I stop the beep from occurring?

Comment: Yes,. and the question is?

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo System Update and Lenovo Vantage do NOT beep to tell you to check for updates.

What you are seeing / hearing is that the download has occurred and now you do need to restart (a) to do the updates and (b) to allow other Apps and Windows to update as well.

The only setting in Lenovo System Update is to for Anonymous Statistic. There are more settings in Vantage but none of them Beep.

So best course of action is to update